# local grunt database errors, when I have a vagrant magento2 box

Tags: magento2, grunt, local, npm

I have a vagrant box (debian) with a Magento2 installation for development. Everything works nice, but changing css/less is very very slow (because everytime I have to remove pub/frontend and var/view_processing/*), developing a theme is not nice in Magento2... :(

That's why I have installed NPM + Grunt on my local Mac. But when I run grunt exec:theme I always get an error:

```
  [Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                       
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I understand that my local Grunt cannot connection my database (because I have a vagrant box), but how can I work with Grunt on my LOCAL environment (ex. PHP Storm), without database connection errors?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, as far as I found, this happens a because a different php instance is being used in your cli compared to the web server.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_phpini.html